# Finding angle with only cosine expressions

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to find the values of angles "a" and "b" based on the following expression, and I am simply trying to figure if it is possible based on just that. "x" is a scalar value:

`-2 cos(2a+b) = cos(2a+2b)+cos(2a)`

I've arrived to this equation after having manipulated the following:

`x = x cos(a+b) + x cos(a)`

`-x = x sin(a+b) + x sin(a)`

Did I go in the wrong direction? I simply equated both above equations and used some identities. Is it solvable using only what I know now?

Comment: What exactly do you want to find? The language is a little confusing.

Comment: I want to find the values of a and b, if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original equations become 
$$
x [\cos (a+b) + \cos(a) -1 ] = 0 \\
x [\sin (a+b) + \sin(a) + 1] = 0.
$$
One solution to these equations is $x = 0$, regardless of the values of $a$ and $b$. For any other value of $x$, we can divide through by $x$ to get
$$
\cos (a+b) + \cos(a) - 1  = 0 \\
\sin (a+b) + \sin(a) + 1 = 0.
$$
Is the question then "What values must $a$ and $b$ have?" One solution, off the top of my head,  is $a = 0, b = -\pi/2$; another is $a = -\pi/2, b = \pi/2.$ My best guess offhand is that these are the only two solutions, but I don't say that with any confidence.

**Post-comment addition**

To solve more generally, I'd put the non-$a+b$ terms on one side:
$$
\cos (a+b) = 1 - \cos(a) \\
\sin(a+b) = -1 - \sin(a)
$$
Squaring both equations and summing, we get
$$
\cos^2(a+b) + \sin^2(a+b) = 1 - 2\cos a + \cos^2 a + 1 + 2\sin a + \sin^2 a
$$
The sine-squared-plus-cos-squared terms both sum to one, to get
$$
1 = 1 - 2\cos a  + 1 + 2\sin a + 1 \\
-2 = - 2( \cos a  - \sin a)\\
1 =  \cos a  - \sin a
$$
Now it's easy to see the answer: because 
\begin{align}
\cos a - \sin a 
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} ( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \cos a-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \sin a) \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} ( \cos \frac{\pi}{4} \cos a-\sin \frac{\pi}{4} \sin a) \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}  \cos (a + \frac{\pi}{4}) 
\end{align}
so that 
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = \cos ( a + \frac{\pi}{4})
\end{align}
whence $a + \frac{\pi}{4}$ is either $\pm \pi/4$.

Comment: If we take the constant on the other side in both equations then we may square and add the equations to, probably, get a simplified version...

Comment: Where did "x" come from?  There is **no** "x" in the original equation.

Comment: The OP's writing is a little unclear, but it appears that OP started with the two equations that involve $x$, diddled around a little, and arrived at the single equation at the top of the question, and asked "how do I solve this single equation." Since OP presumably really wants a solution to the original pair, that's what I gave.

Comment: @SaranshKumar: squaring may introduce extraneous solutions, but aside from that (which requires us to check any solution we find), I agree completely.

Comment: You understood my question correctly, although I apologize it wasn't unclear. The correct answer was indeed  a=−π/2,b=π/2, although you seem to have done it mentally and I was trying to find a way to do it using the equation systems. If the angles were harder to calculate mentally, could it have been done otherwise and how?

Comment: See notes. The trick of converting a sum of a sine and a cosine into a cosine (or sine) of a sum of angles is a useful one for the future.